# How to setup two different servers in two different machines?

Tags: android, python, flask, server, raspberry-pi

I am doing a project using Android and Raspberry Pi. 
There will be only one central server and more than one RPi. There will be more than one user. 
Now the user needs to communicate with the RPi.

1. So, the user will connect to the RPi via the server running on the
   RPi and send a request.
2. The RPi will do some processes inside it.
3. Then the RPi will send the data to the main server.
4. The main server will process the data and send the response to the RPi.
5. The RPi will receive the response from the Main Server and then it will send the response back to the Android app.

i.e. I need to send request from Mobile --> RPi , RPi --> Main Server and then response will flow from Main Server --> RPi , RPi --> Mobile

How do I achieve it?

Also, how do I communicate from one server to other?

Currently I am running Flask Server in RPi. Also I need to use Flask as the main server also.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's an assignment and not a question.

Comment: This is not an assignment. I need to communicate from Flask server in RPi to another Flask server in main server. How do i achieve it

Comment: Requesting someone to design a system for you is an assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Please be noted that a server can be a client also. Hence, there should be no problems.

> I need to send request from Mobile --> RPi , RPi --> Main Server and
>   then response will flow from Main Server --> RPi , RPi --> Mobile
>
> How do I achieve it?

1. Your Main Server is a Http Server.
2. Your RPi Server is also a Http Server.
3. From Android devices, use Retrofit to make a request to your selected RPi, then after calculating, the RPi uses a Http Client to request to MainServer. Since all are Http Requests, the responses should go back smoothly. There is just one note: the code of RPi has to wait for response from main server before returning to Android devices.

> Also, how do I communicate from one server to other?

Not sure what you mean here, if you want to communicate between servers and they are in the same machine (different port), you can use message (IPC). If they are on different machines (i.e different ip addresses), you can use Http Requests. There are others options like: push notification to send data to multiple clients.

*The idea is to be flexible in thinking, a server is a place to receive and process request. If it needs a response from another server, then it will play a client role in this case*

Comment: OK! Is it possible to send files from RPi to Main server via FTP?

Comment: Yes, definitely. Just find a FTP client library such as: https://docs.python.org/2/library/ftplib.html and enjoy